# jmeter certificate is not created

Tags: jmeter

I start want to record in jmeter 1st time.

My steps were:

1. I installed jmeter in mac: `brew install jmeter`
2. I created new Recording template
3. I click start button. It display a pop up as in picture below.

It display a pop up as in picture below.

[image]

However, when I go to check the file in `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/3.2/bin`  or in `/usr/local/bin` directories it does not exists. I am not sure which one it should be located.
Only possible reason that I found myself was using of wrong version of java. I use java 8, so it shouldn't be a problem in my case. I do not see any errors. When I start and stop again I see the log as in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably JMeter cannot write in the folder.

Edit user.properties and modify:

> proxy.cert.directory

See this blog to know where to find configuration files:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/using-homebrew-to-install-and-configure-jmeter-under-mac-osx/

Comment: proxy.cert.directory does not appear in this file. Can you suggest what I need to add there?

Comment: It is in jmeter.properties, just copy it in user and update path so that it points to a folder where Jmeter can write

Comment: Thanks! Your answers helped. May be you could also clarify what is the purpose of this certificate?

Comment: ask another question for that, comments are not well suited for that

Answer (score 0):

**Configuracion en MacOS con instalacion con gestor Homebrew**

If when you run JMeter you don't know where the certificate is generated, you must change the address where the certificate is created. (In my case I could not create the certificate in ) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v8Bt.png)

To change the configuration file, you must go to:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.1/libexec/bin
```

and there access the file `user.properties` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOTu7.png)

1. we open with `sudo vim jmeter.properties`
2. we modify proxy.cert.directory = Desired path (in my case

> /Users/admin/certJmeter

)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4imp.png)

Once this is done, the certificate will be created for us in that route.

It is very important to restart jmeter again for the creation to be done correctly.

we close and open:

```
open /usr/local/bin/jmeter
```

we execute recording:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9mvi.jpg)

and certificate is generated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFFvS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57XSA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try running jmeter from terminal using superuser:

sudo jmeter

It will install certificate by itself.