# JMeter Certificate "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt" not generated when recording test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

When I launch JMeter and start a recording in the "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" a window pops-up indicating that a Root CA certificate has been generated in the JMeter *bin* directory, but when I go to the *bin* directory there isn't any certificate there.
I am using JMeter 5.4.1 on Windows 10.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127474/jmeter-certificate-is-not-created), I tried launching JMeter with administrator permissions and checked the permissions of the *bin* directory but still no certificate was generated.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053346/apachejmetertemporaryrootca-crt-not-generated), I also tried to delete the files *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt*, *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr* and *proxyserver.jks* from the *bin* directory. Afterwards, I launched JMeter again and started the recorder but still no certificate was generated.

I also tried using a different version of JMeter and downloaded version 5.4.3, but the certificate was still not generated.

[EDIT]

According to Dmitri T's suggestion, the jmeter log can be viewed [here](https://github.com/TomasRibeiro96/stack_overflow-questions/blob/main/jmeter.log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I managed to find a solution to my problem. The value I had on the system and user variable *_JAVA_OPTIONS* was causing the failure. I deleted those variables and the certificate was generated again.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help without seeing your [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), better with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/).

Look for the following line:

```
ProxyControl: Created keystore in
```

it will contain the path where the certificates are created. If not the log file will display the error.

You may also find [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) easier to use, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: I updated the question to include a link to the logs. If you need anything else then feel free to ask.

Comment: I am using the Chrome extension but, for my current use case, the JMeter recording is better because I'm handling requests with several dynamic parameters and I need to figure out where they appeared on previous requests.